# Общий метод для изменения значения приватных переменных в классе

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пишу систему сохранения в игре. Создал класс, где хранятся все необходимые и используемые в игре переменные (различных типов). Переменные, естественно, все приватные. Так вот в чем суть вопроса: для изменения значений этих переменных внутри класса необходимо создавать методы, в которых указанные параметры будут принимать указанные значения, чтобы их можно было изменять в других классах, и под каждую переменную нужно прописать свой отдельный метод - а нельзя ли сделать один "шаблонный" метод, куда отправлять, скажем, название переменной и ее значение и присваивать там и назначать все соответственно? Или ничего так не получится и нужно писать миллион методов (по количеству используемых переменных в игре) без вариантов?

Приведу пример:

```
//Мы хотим изменить значение переменной param1, (который отвечает за силу) в основном классе (приведен дальше ниже) из этого класса:
public class Someclass
{
    int param1; (отвечает за силу, например)
    string param2;

    //Отправляем переменную в метод основного класса чтобы ее значение там изменилось
    ChangeValues(param1, param1.name);
}

//Есть основной класс и в нем находятся переменные и методы
public class Mainclass
{
    //Переменные различных типов, используемые в игре
    int param1 { get; private set; } //Отвечает за силу
    string param2 { get; private set; }

    //Пишем так званый Общий метод для изменения переменных
    public ChangeValues(param, param.name)
    {
        param.name = param;
    }
```

}

Код, естественно, с ошибками - я просто попытался донести в таком виде логику происходящего, чтобы было понятнее (надеюсь). У кого какие варианты будут? Или я зря трачу время и лучше бы потратил его на написание методов?

Comment: `Переменные, естественно, все приватные.` зачем делать свойства приватными, если вы хотите задавать им значения вне класса?

Comment: @iikuzmychov а зачем вообще делают переменные приватными? Вместо минусовать вопрос - посоветовали бы что по сути.. А так - только нагадили и написали ни о чем.. Фу

Comment: @skroliks переменные делают приватными явно не для того, чтобы потом их извне изменять. Вместо того, чтобы сделать паблик сеттер у свойства, ты плодишь методы под каждое свойство. Для чего? Тот псевдокод, что ты приложил к вопросу никак не делает его более понятным, лучше замени его на реальный код, где у тебя проблема возникает. Для сохранения, выдели интерфейс с методами save/load и реализуй его там, где нужно сохранение

Comment: @KOTlK вот, уже хоть что-то со смыслом ) Я же почему и написал спросил у кого какие мысли по этому поводу и как может лучше это все можно сделать, а не минусовать за вопрос, какой не понравился.. Я просто изначально сохранял все переменные в PlayerPrefs, но, как оказалось, это не очень практично и вообще не подходит, учитывая, что я хочу в дальнейшем хранить все сохранения на сервере. Вот и решил сделать отдельный класс на замену PlayerPrefs с переменными, только делать их все открытыми - как-то противоречит той же инкапсуляции, да и безопасности данных игры в целом. Так и что делать то? ((

Comment: @skroliks выделить интерфейс и реализовать его там, где надо сохранение, как я выше и написал

Comment: @skroliks во первых, я не минусовал вопрос, и просто спросил вашу мотивацию делать переменные приватными, когда вы хотите их изменять из вне. А во-вторых, мой вопрос напрямую связан с тем чтобы понять что и почему вы делаете и помочь вам

Comment: @KOTlK не совсем понимаю, что значит "реализовать его там, где надо сохранение". У меня есть статический класс с методами загрузки и сохранения, но он получается при записи сохраняет абсолютно все предусмотренные параметры (а не выборочно какой-то один), при этом - я хочу чтобы все данные сохранялись в один файл, а нужные переменные разбросаны по разным скриптам, вот и пытаюсь все собрать до кучи..

Comment: @iikuzmychov ну смотрите, у персонажа в игре есть, например, опыт (на самом деле подобных параметров большое множество), эта переменная хранится в отдельном классе для персонажа. Однако, опыт этот получается в том числе за победу в бою, который происходит вообще в отдельной сцене, при этом мне же нужно этот опыт персонажу как-то прибавлять.. А если я буду хранить эту переменную в открытом виде (паблик) - разве это не откроет доступ к возможности читерить и "рисовать" тот же опыт участнику (кто знает, как это делать)?

Comment: @skroliks написал ответ, там показал что это значит

Comment: модификаторы доступа никоем образом не влияют на возможность читерить, они лишь устанавливают соглашения для использования помеченных ими членов класса в вызывающем коде. Чтобы "нарисовать" опыт, достаточно найти адрес в памяти/запись в реестре/запись в файле где будет хранится этот опыт и поменять его значение

Comment: @iikuzmychov так вот поэтому я и назначаю переменным приват, а через отдельные публичные методы меняю им значение, чтобы нельзя было найти эту переменную и изменить по адресу - разве не правильно делаю?

Comment: private/public это всё API си-шарпа, это никак не влияет на доступ к адресу в памяти или файле. Прошу погуглите как работают читы

Comment: @iikuzmychov вот и вам тогда вопрос тот же: зачем тогда вообще переменные делать приватными, если разницы нет и на "взлом" не влияет? ))

Comment: @iikuzmychov и вот еще - чисто в теории даже, для защиты от взлома через оперативную память (или как там оно правильно обзывается) через программу - объявление переменной приватной и изменение ее через отдельный метод, вместо просто объявления публичной - не защитит разве от такого взлома (где определяют адрес переменной по ее значению и потом просто изменяют значение)?

Comment: конечно не защитит, это никак не связано. `зачем тогда вообще переменные делать приватными` для того чтобы программисту, использующему класс ненароком не нарушить работу этого класса, пользуясь его "внутренней кухней", что приведёт к долгим часам отладки и поиска ошибок. Это единственная причина. Инкапсуляцией - это защита от неправильного использования класса, не более. И даже в самом C# ничто не мешает изменить значение приватного поля через [рефлексию](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/14.1.php), что уж там говорить об изменении значения в памяти

Comment: [Википедия: что такое инкапсуляция в C#](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)#C#)

Comment: @iikuzmychov вот, теперь все немного прояснилось, спасибо! А то совсем уже по ходу запутался был в этом всем (( (почему я инкапсуляцию защитой считал - вообще хз как так вышло - видимо виной всему ролики разных блогеров, где нетолково все поясняют, либо сам просто изначально не в ту сторону смотрел..

Comment: рад, что помог разобраться

Answer (score 0):

Интерфейс для сохранения:

```
public interface ISaveLoad
{
    void Save(ISerialization serialization);
    void Load(IDeserialization deserialization);
}
```

Для сохранения/загрузки данных:

```
public interface ISerialization
{
    void SaveInt(int value);
    void SaveFloat(float value);
    void SaveVector3(Vector3 value);
}

public interface IDeserialization
{
    int LoadInt();
    float LoadFloat();
    Vector3 LoadVector3();
}
```

Реализуешь интерфейс ISaveLoad в том месте, где нужно сохранить поля объекта

```
public class Character : ISaveLoad
{
    private float _power;
    private int _level;
    private Vector3 _position;
        
    public void Save(ISerialization serialization)
    {
        serialization.SaveFloat(_power);
        serialization.SaveInt(_level);
        serialization.SaveVector3(_position);
    }

    public void Load(IDeserialization deserialization)
    {
        _power = deserialization.LoadFloat();
        _level = deserialization.LoadInt();
        _position = deserialization.LoadVector3();
    }
}
```

В методе сохранения игры проходишься по всему, что нужно сохранить, вызываешь Save.
В методе загрузки вызываешь Load.

Куда и как сохранять данные (ISerialization/IDeserialization) решай сам, хоть в playerprefs, хоть json, хоть в бинарном виде.

Comment: У меня все реализовано точно так же, только не через интерфейсы, а через статические классы (как по мне - разницы не вижу, да и не в этом суть). У меня вопрос совсем в другом (не про то, как сейвить и читать переменные): для сохранения инкапусляции переменных приходится под каждую прописывать отдельный метод для ее изменения, а я спрашиваю - возможно ли сделать какой-то один универсальный метод, чтобы только отправлять туда нужные значения и получать в итоге изменение в нужных параметрах, а не писать миллион раздельных методов?

Comment: @skroliks тем, что ты значение переменной изменяешь не из сеттера свойства, а из отдельного метода, никак не сохраняет тебе инкапсуляцию. Не знаю, кто тебе про такую дырявую мистическую инкапсуляцию рассказал, но лучше не слушай его больше.

Comment: да во всех роликах тех же на ютьюбе везде учат так )) Зачем тогда вообще скрывать переменные и делать их приватными?

Comment: @skroliks ответил на "зачем" в комментариях к вопросу